# How to pass a filename via URL?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to pass filenames via the url, e.g.:

```
http://example.com/images/niceplace.jpg
```

The problem I'm having is when the file name contains a blank character, e.g.:

```
http://example.com/images/nice place.jpg
```

or

```
http://example.com/images/nice%20place.jpg
```

For these two URLs, codeigniter complains about the blank char: "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

How should I go about fixing this?

I know I can add the blank character to the `permitted_uri_chars` in `config.php` but I'm looking for a better solution as there might be other disallowed characters in a filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution.

The URL is generated using `rawurlencode()`.

Then, within the `images` controller, the filename is decoded using `rawurldecode(html_entity_decode($filename))`.

I successfully tested this solution with a few special characters I can think of and with UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

http://php.net/urlencode

Actually, you will run into another issues, when a filename would contain `&` character, and a few others. urlencode would get rid of all the possible issues.

Comment: He's using codeigniter, and because of this framework, it's not allowing him to use certain characters. So it's not as simple as just using urlencode/urldecode.

Comment: Thanks @DaveChen, I was trying to make `urlencode` work without any luck.

Comment: Alternatively if you want specified character for space i.e. %  or other chars to be allowed in the URL then update your config.php file $config['permitted_uri_chars']

Answer (score 0):

This configuration option is created to avoid some characters being passed in [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) and you want to walkaround it in some cases. I think most appropriate solutions are:

1. Pass file name as a parameter - http://domain.com/images/?image=test.jpg
2. Remove all non alfanumeric characters and may be some other (dash, underscore, etc) from file name when you save it. In my opinion, it is better, because you can face other problems with some character in other cases.

Comment: The first solution faces the same "disallowed characters in URI" problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of the better way to work with url's for specified condition is to encode/encrypt your url parameters using encryption/security class in order to maintain URL security:

```
$encrypt=$this->encrypt->encode($param1) & $this->encrypt->decode($encrypt)
```

Alternatively if you want special chars to be allowed in the URL then change your config settings in config.php file.

```
File Location: application/config/config.php
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

Add all characters in right side that you want to be allowed with your application.