# PHP Looped files from MySQL get overwritten by last looped file

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am trying to loop comments with their associated files from MySQL previewing every file as a link. But when i click any file to download somehow all files are overwritten by the last looped file. I checked to see if files were overwritten when uploaded but discovered that they are fine. For more clarification the name of PHP page containing the following code is called `ticketinfo.php`.

Edit: also `$ticketID` is a variable that contains the ID of ticket queried from MySQL

```
<?php
//Loading each comment with its user's name and file
$query8 = "SELECT comments.commentID,comments.userID,comments.content,comments.file,comments.file_name,comments.file_mime,comments.file_size,users.name FROM comments JOIN users ON comments.userID=users.id WHERE ticketID=:ticketID";
$stmt8 = $connection->prepare($query8);
$stmt8->bindParam('ticketID',$ticketID,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt8->execute();
$count8 = $stmt8->rowCount();
if($count8 > 0){
  while($row8 = $stmt8->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $commentID = $row8["commentID"];
    $cfilesize = $row8["file_size"];
    $cfiletype = $row8["file_mime"];
    $cfilename = $row8["file_name"];
    $cfile = $row8["file"];
    $userID = $row8["userID"];

    echo nl2br($row8["name"].": ".$row8["content"]."\n"."<label>Files: </label>"
                   ."<a href='ticketinfo.php?comment_id=$commentID'>$cfilename</a>"."\n\n");
  }
}else {
  echo "Error no comments";
}

//In case comment file is clicked
if(isset($_GET["comment_id"])){
  header("Content-length: $cfilesize");
  header("Content-Type: $cfiletype");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$cfilename");
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  echo $cfile;
  exit;
 }
```

Comment: `$query8 = "SELECTcomments.commentID,comments......` are you sure you are not missing a space there ??

Comment: No that was just a copy paste thing

Comment: LOL, on copy/paste a space got lost...... Would you be so kind to report this as a bug ?  (I am not sure where you can report such a bug.... )

Comment: No i was just spacing the code after pasting it in the body section so it must be a mistake from my side but it has nothing to do with the site or the code error

Comment: In `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$cfilename");` - `$cfilename` is always the last file from the list.  You need to find which one corresponds to the `$_GET["comment_id"]` (or perhaps just pass the file name)

Comment: How do i pass filename from the link?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798572/how-to-pass-a-filename-via-url, and replace the value in `$commentID`.